# modify the message based on the number of inputs

Tags: java

I have the following method which accepts a string of carcodes separated by a comma (it can be a single car code as well) and holdReason but my question is about carcodes.

For example, the carcodes can be like the following: `"ABC1234, TYZ8765"`

```
public PostReturn scan(String carcode, String holdReason) {
    PostReturn pr = new PostReturn();
    if (Utils.nullOrBlank(carcode)) {
        // cannot lookup
        pr.setErrorMsg("No carcode to lookup");
        return pr;
    }

    // trim it first/remove white spaces
    String[] carcodes = carcode.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
    for (String carId: carcodes) {
        Kitcarcode kb = Kitcarcode.parsecarcode(carId);
        if (kb == null) {
            // invalid carId
            pr.setErrorMsg(carId + " was invalid - could not be parsed");
            return pr;
        }
        // lookup the kit
        CarHandler cph = CarHandler.findByKitcarcode(kb);
        // mark it as on hold
        cph.setAttribute(CarHandler.PREPROCESSING_HOLD_DATE, Utils.getDateAsMDYYYY(new Date()));
        cph.setAttribute(CarHandler.PREPROCESSING_HOLD_REASON, holdReason);
        cph.storeChanges();
        carProcessing(kb, cph);
        // confirm msg
        pr.setSuccessMsg(kb + " is marked as on carprocessing hold for reason: " + holdReason);
    }
    return pr;
}
```

I'm mainly concerned about this line of code:
 `pr.setSuccessMsg(kb + " is marked as on carprocessing hold for reason: " + holdReason);`

If there are multiple car codes, separated by comma, for example  `"ABC1234,TYZ8765"`

the message printed by the above line of code is `TYZ8765 is marked as on carprocessing hold for reason xyz`. Since there are two carcodes , is it possible to print it like the following?

`ABC1234 and TYZ8765 are marked as on carprocessing hod for reason xyz`

Comment: too many empty lines, I'm too tired to scroll down and check the whole code :-/ (And is this question about how to *replace* `,` with `and` ? Or just how to concatenate the strings (already being done in posted code) ? )

Comment: Just updated it. It's a question about displaying a proper message based on the number of inputs. Right now it only displays the message with the last array item.

Comment: I may be wrong, still to many empty lines, but seems like it should display each array item on a separate line. Anyway, I would use a string variable, declared outside the loop, to collect each item (using string concatenation, or even a `Formatter`) and build the message while looping

Comment: Code edited and excess blank lines have been removed.  As has already been mentioned by @user16320675, it is best to avoid having too much unnecessary white-space in code. It makes the code more difficult to read than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the reason the message being printed only contains the last *carcode* is because the *for-loop* it's within, will simply over-write the previous *pr.setSuccessMsg* call during each iteration.

Since *pr* and *holdReason* are not changed within the *for-loop*, you can place it after the *for-loop*.

Additionally, from within the *for-loop*, you can populate a *String* value with the  *kb* values.

We'll utilize the *for-loop* to increment a *count* value.
This will be used to determine if our *strings* value is being populated with 1, 2, or more *kb* values—which will determine if our *strings* value should contain commas or an *"and"*.

We can further use the *count* value, after the *for-loop* is exited, to determine if we should be using *"is"*, or *"and"*.

The *strings* value is then used as the message sent to the *setSuccessMsg* method.

```java
PostReturn pr = new PostReturn();
if (Utils.nullOrBlank(carcode)) {
    // cannot lookup
    pr.setErrorMsg("No carcode to lookup");
    return pr;
}
// trim it first/remove white spaces
String[] carcodes = carcode.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder();
int count = 0, length = carcodes.length;
for (String carId : carcodes) {
    Kitcarcode kb = Kitcarcode.parsecarcode(carId);
    if (kb == null) {
        // invalid carId
        pr.setErrorMsg(carId + " was invalid - could not be parsed");
        return pr;
    }
    // lookup the kit
    CarHandler cph = CarHandler.findByKitcarcode(kb);
    // mark it as on hold
    cph.setAttribute(CarHandler.PREPROCESSING_HOLD_DATE, Utils.getDateAsMDYYYY(new Date()));
    cph.setAttribute(CarHandler.PREPROCESSING_HOLD_REASON, holdReason);
    cph.storeChanges();
    carProcessing(kb, cph);
    if (count != 0) {
        if (length > 2) strings.append(", ");
        if (count == length - 1) {
            if (count == 1) strings.append(' ');
            strings.append("and ");
        }
    }
    strings.append(kb);
    count++;
}
strings.append(count == 1 ? " is " : " are ");
strings.append("marked as on carprocessing hold for reason: ");
strings.append(holdReason);
// confirm msg
pr.setSuccessMsg(strings.toString());
return pr;
```

As an example, printing the *strings* value would yield a similar output.

```
ABC123, DEF456, and GHI789 are marked as on carprocessing hold for reason: 
ABC123 and DEF456 are marked as on carprocessing hold for reason: 
ABC123 is marked as on carprocessing hold for reason:
```

Comment: Thanks. I think comma-separated makes more sense. I guess it will be more hassle if I want to display `and` just before the last array item as `and` would make more sense. And I believe I could use `is/are marked as on car processing hold for reason:` so that this piece of text is applicable for singe and multiple array elements. I am going to give it a try.

Comment: @Tan, glad it helped.  It depends on who the end-user is, or consumer.  I tend to find that most computer generated values will just be comma separated.  Whereas, a publication will typically be in a correct grammar.  If it _is_ something that you think requires singular and plural grammar, and also a final _"and"_ on the last item, I could show you how to implement that as well.  It's just a for-loop, and some conditional statements, not a lot of code.

Comment: Sure, that would be great if it's possible to look into those scenarios.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update the original answer with your new solution? I'm getting little confused with where to put the loop content. Thanks

Comment: @Tan, no problem, I updated the answer.  I should have used the same variable names, actually.